# How to edit the template of comments of method in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, ide

The default value is like

```
/**
     * 
     * @param context
     * @param fileName
     * @return
     */
```

when I print"/**" and enter.
But I can hardly find somewhere to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Open **File > Settings** or **Intellij Idea > Preferences** (Mac OS), and write 'templates' to search bar, after click like on image.

[image]

Comment: Sorry,but I edit the Implemented Method Body,nothing happened

Comment: I get it what you want, in current version it's impossible, but i don't get it, what you want to customize?

Comment: The version I use is 12.1.6,I want the comments more Customized

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about editing it, but if all you want to do is turn it off - disable:

> "/Settings/IDE Settings/Editor/Smart Keys/Insert documentation comment
>   stub"

After that, it won't insert those javadoc tags anymore.

Comment: I glad to use it,only want to make it more customized